# Pagespeed rating low - What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a webpage with a 100% rating from Google PageSpeed, not an easy task let me tell you! So far, I have the caching enabled, header compression enabled, compressed all my png images, and I am attempting to async my CSS for above the fold content. The last bit is where I am running into issues. Here's the current layout of the page in a codepen:

https://codepen.io/ftbcoders/pen/MPVbNY

I have defined my stylesheets in the footer with `media="none"`, I have set a pre-load animation and loader using inline CSS so you see a loader, called an `onLoad event` on the body to change the `media` type of the CSS files from `none` to `all` when the document is loaded, and yet I am getting:

```
Optimization

Low
56 / 100

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
Your page has 3 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting
for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking
resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.

Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:

https://www.example.com/stylesheet/style.css
https://www.example.com/stylesheet/open.sans.css
https://www.example.com/stylesheet/font.awesome.css
```

Why are they blocking loading? They are set for `media` of `none` so it should load the CSS files but not try and display them until the body `onLoad` event has fired, AND they're in the very end of my file... what am I missing here? It's loading awesome in practice but the ranking is what I am wanting to maximize here. Any tips? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Your site is on plane html javascript or using any language like php,java etc?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

Comment: @Gerard Copying that exact function they use still returns the same rating

Answer (score 0):

Each CSS file contains styles with information how each your HTML tag looks like in the end => it's not possible to render page without that information => browser has to download, parse that information in order to show the page => it's render-blocking asset.

There are multiple ways to solve that, and I'll show one of them. Relatively simple. 
You may include contents of those CSS files in your HTML file. That will solve issue.
In your HTML instead of a link to .css file

```
<link ... href="style.css">
```

put contents of those file

```
<style>
contents of your style.css here
</style>
```

Ideally that should be done programmatically.

It can be applied in production if those css files are not that big and/or you don't have a lot of returning visitors.

Comment: NEVER include your entire CSS file on the page using style tags. I am aware of how CSS loading works, if you view my Codepen you can see I am using a style selector for basic layout while the content loads asynchronously. After the page loads, javascript is employed to import the loaded css files. It works great, but the pagespeed sees them as render blocking even though the browser is told to load them without rendering their content. This is the issue.

Comment: This is actually terrible advice. While limiting http requests is a good thing, so is caching CSS (and for that matter  js) resources separately. By all means use bundling to combine many CSS resources into one to reduce http requests, but aim keep the CSS separate to the HTML

Comment: Looks like guys you missed the last sentence of my post.Potentially I had to stress on that more, like mark it bold.